# Can't get my data sorted as needed in query results using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have query that displays the results as follows:

[image]

However, I need the query results to be displayed as follows:

[image]

Here is my query code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #tempRecordsWithoutSUBJ 
WHERE [Policy Number] = 'EAA1396891' --'EAA1380770'
GROUP BY [RN], [RTN], [AM Best Number], [Policy Number], [Line of Business (LOB)], [Transaction Effective Date], [Data Fields], [PolicySysID], [Record Type]
ORDER BY RN, [Record Type];
```

What I'm needing is to have the PROP and PRP1 records for each POLR record. There are 3 PROP and 3 corresponding PRP1 records and I need them sorted under each POLR record as displayed in the 2nd image. I added ROW_NUMBER to each section of the code to help but obviously I'm struggling.  Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really unclear how the records are "corresponding". Other than the record type POLR/PROP/PRP1, what distinguishes each POLR record? What ties a specific PROP record to a POLR record?

Comment: You're correct Ross, my apologies.  In addition to the RECORD TYPE, what distinguishes each POLR record is the DATA FIELDS value and then I had added the RN value to each record.

Comment: Please post sample data as text and not images. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Why are you grouping by every column a using a `SELECT *`? Where are your aggregate functions?

Comment: @Larnu so she can get a DISTINCT with ORDER BY, I'm assuming.

Comment: Yes, Tab Alleman, to answer @Larnu question.

Comment: You could type a couple hundred fewer characters of code use DISTINCT instead of the group by.

Comment: But you can use `ORDER BY` with a query with `DISTINCT` as well... :/ In truth, I find it a little ironic that you declare every column in your `GROUP BY`, but don't in your `SELECT`; as there's a lot of people out there that are not a fan of `SELECT *` (especially with compiled objects).

Comment: Use of a group by clause does not guarantee any order. A resultset generated by a sql statement that does not contain an order by clause has no defined order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've provided, it looks like your requirement is to return all of the `RTN=1` rows, each one with a full set of 2&3 rows under it, in order of `RN,RTN`.

If that's right, seems like one way to get this is with a UNION ALL that duplicates the 2&3 for each 1, then supplies an artificial column for ordering.

```
SELECT * , RTN AS Ord
FROM..WHERE..AND RTN=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT t1.* , t2.RTN AS Ord
FROM myTable t1
CROSS JOIN myTable t2
WHERE..AND t1.RTN<>1 AND t2.RTN=1
ORDER BY Ord,RN,RTN
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I see what I missed.  We need to actually use `RN` AS `Ord`, and we also need to add one more artificial column to force the `POLR` records to the top of their grouping.   So more like this:

```
SELECT *, RN AS Ord, 1 AS Ord2
FROM myTable 
WHERE..AND RTN=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT t1.* , t2.RN AS Ord, 2 AS Ord2
FROM myTable t1
CROSS JOIN myTable t2
WHERE..AND t1.RTN<>1 AND t2.RTN=1
ORDER BY Ord,Ord2,RN,RTN
```

I tested this and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    L1 char(1)
 ,  I1 int
 ,  I2 int
);

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES 
    ('a',1,1)
,   ('a',1,2)
,   ('c',2,1)
,   ('d',3,1)
,   ('c',2,2)
,   ('d',3,2)
;

SELECT *, I2 AS Ord, 1 AS Ord2
FROM #tmp
WHERE I1=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT t1.*, t2.I2 AS Ord, 2 AS Ord2
FROM #tmp t1
CROSS JOIN #tmp t2
WHERE t1.I1<>1 AND t2.I1=1
ORDER BY Ord, Ord2, I2, I1
;


DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Comment: so what happens is that there are 2 POLR records but there are 3 PROP and 3 PRP1 records so my last 2 records above have no POLR record to attach to (lack of a better phrase) and consequently I have only the last 2 records without a POLR record.  Is there away to fix that?  Would separate CTE statements possible help?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you're describing, can you show the difference between what you get with the above and what you posted as your desired result?

Comment: Sorry, Tab.  The same results as the first image are displayed with the added ORD column where all the values are displayed as 1 for that column.  Here is the query I used:
SELECT DISTINCT *, RTN as Ord 
FROM #tempRecordsWithoutSUBJ 
WHERE RTN = 1 
AND [Policy Number] = 'EAA1396891' --'EAA1380770'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*, t2.RTN as Ord
FROM #tempRecordsWithoutSUBJ t1
CROSS JOIN #tempRecordsWithoutSUBJ t2
WHERE t1.[Policy Number] = 'EAA1396891'
AND t2.[Policy Number] = 'EAA1396891' 
AND t1.RTN <> 1 
AND t2.RTN =1
ORDER BY Ord, RN, RTN

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'll be able to get back on this later this afternoon or next week as I just got a higher priority assignment.  Thank you very much for your time and help.  I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: your solution worked brilliantly.  Thank you very much for your help and time.  I wish I could put additional points to your credit.